# Trigger for custom metdata object

Tags: metadata, custom-metadata

Is it possible to create trigger to custom meatada object ?

Assume I have metadata object called MyMetaData ,

I want to create trigger to MyMetaData , for example before insert new instance of MyMetaData .

Answer (score 4):

Its not possible to write a trigger on custom metadata object or Custom Settings .

If you need trigger you will need to use custom object .Also insert of custom metadata is also currently not possible via apex .

Comment: With Summer 17 at least MDT are insertable via Apex and support validation